# Syntax of final, override, const with trailing return types

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

I'm trying to override a virtual but also use the keywords `override`, `final` and `const`, with trailing return type. The problem seems to be in the derived class, and the compiler error (saying that I did not specify the trailing return type) is not too helpful. The code is here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/zh3hD4Ukgrg6txyE

And also pasted below. I've played around with different ordering but still can't seem to get it correct. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::ostream;
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//Base stuff
class Base
{
public:
  Base(int i=2):bval(i){}
  virtual ~Base()=default;
  virtual auto debug(ostream& os=cout)const->ostream&;

private:
  int bval=0;
};

auto Base::debug(ostream& os) const->ostream&
{
  os << "bval: " << bval << endl;
  return os;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
//Derived stuff
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived(int i=2,int j=3):Base(i), dval(j){}
  ~Derived()=default;

  auto debug(ostream& os=cout) const override final->ostream&; // error here

private:
  int dval=0;
};

auto Derived::debug(ostream& os) const override final->ostream&
{
  os << "dval: " << dval << endl;
  return os;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
//Testing!
int main()
{
  Base b(42);
  b.debug()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: small bit, you don't need ~Derived()=default; right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

1. [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) and [final](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) should appear after the member function declaration, which including the trailing return type specification, i.e.

   ```
   auto debug(ostream& os=cout) const ->ostream& override final;
   ```
2. `override` and `final` should not be used with the member function definition outside the class definition, so just remove them:

   ```
   auto Derived::debug(ostream& os) const ->ostream&
   {
     os << "dval: " << dval << endl;
     return os;
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh, of course, forgot to return `os`, thanks! Question: How do you remember the syntax for these specifications, or is it just something one would pick up with time? Or is there some rule I should know about? I'm always having trouble remembering what should be only in the class member declarations and what can be in both declaration and definition, and have trouble knowing what goes where (i.e. the trailing return should be before `override` and `const`).

Comment: @pss _what can be in both declaration and definition_ -- my rule of thumb: if you can overload on something, it must be in both declaration and definition.

Comment: @pss Trailing return type specification is part of function declaration (i.e. a part of the function signature), but `final` and `override` is not. So you shouldn't put them into the middle of the function declaration. And as part of the function signature, trailing return type specification could (and should) be specified for both declaration and definition, but `final` and `override` could only be specified inside the class definition; they're used for some features relevant with class and inheritance, but not implementations.